# React - Adding a tab to navbar that manipulates page data instead of invoking route redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react App and I am using Browser router and a component named Navigation for navigation.

I want to know how to add a tab to the Nav that is not for navigation, but instead allows the user to manipulate a components JSX on a specific page.

I do not know how to structure this. I figure I could use the Context API (maybe?) but before I go down that rabbit hole I figure someone might know a different/better way.

Here is some dummy code

**Nav.js**

```
import React from "react";

    function Navigation(props){

        console.log(props)

       return(

           <ul>
             <a href="/"> <li>Landing</li> </a>
             <a href="/test"> <li>Test</li> </a>

              <button>Invoke some action on /test</button>
              {/* If I am on a page named /test I want this button to have the abillity to trigger a function on that page*/}

           </ul>

    )
}


export default Navigation
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Navigation from "./Navigation";
import Test from "./Test";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import {Switch} from 'react-router';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


function App(props) {

  return (
    <div className="App">
    <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Navigation/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/test" component={Test} />
                    <Route exact path="/some-stuff" component={Whatever} />
                    <Route exact path="/some-more-stuff" component={WhateverElse} />
                    <Redirect from="/*" to="/test" />
                </Switch>
             </div>   
        </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: what you want to do with tab ?? we are not getting your point.

Comment: I don't understand the second paragraph. Do you want to declare the routes in your ```App``` component but Links in ```Nav```?

Comment: I want to be able to add a tab to the nav and when the user clicks it it invokes a function on a specific page/component that manipulates THAT page components JSX. Is that clear?

Comment: So change something on a different page than you are currently on? That page is not visible right?

Comment: No change something on the page that I am currently on. In the example I posted I use a component named Test as an example.

Comment: I changed the code slightly to hopefully be more clear